# Accessing archaic Greek Koppa in the birkmult document class

Tags: fonts, symbols

I will be submitting the final version of an article to Birkhauser using the required birkmult document class.

https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=birkmult+document+class&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=5jT7VJq6HOmp8we_mYHIDw#channel=fs&q=birkmult+document+class+tex

https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=birkmult+document+class&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=5jT7VJq6HOmp8we_mYHIDw

It turns out that there are errors when I want to include the [`teubner` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/teabner). This prevents me from accessing the archaic Greek Koppa which I have used in earlier publication on the topic.

[image]

Is there a way around to access this archaic letter?

Comment: The magic word is `MWE`... You have been here a while, so please help users to help you ;-)

Comment: Since it seems quite difficult to download the `birkmult.cls` (I only found a copy from 1994), can you tell where it is available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access that symbol by loading the `LGR` font encoding and declaring

```
\newcommand\Koppa{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\char21\endgroup}
```

so you don't have to load the `teubner` package.

MWE (tried with `birkmult.cls` downloaded from http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/numerik/mt/trunk/birkmult.cls and works fine)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\Koppa{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\char21\endgroup}

\begin{document}

This is my archaic Greek Koppa: \Koppa

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the bump, but is there any way to modify the implementation so that it also works between $$ and in math environments? Right now, it completely breaks my document if enclosed in either of these structures.